# QML not loading Module Plugins, dll files not loading, says Not Enough Space to process Command

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qml, qt-creator

I have been developing an Application, having features to chose the theme color of application, for that, I want to use QML ColorDialogue. But it gives me a problem.
Here is my code for ColorDialogue

```
ColorDialog {
    id: colorDialog
    title: "Please choose a color"
    onAccepted: {
        console.log("You chose: " + colorDialog.color)     
    }
    onRejected: {
        console.log("Canceled")
    }
    Component.onCompleted: visible = true
}
```

And the Error which I get is

```
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/main.qml:41 Type OptionBar unavailable
qrc:/OptionBar.qml:99 Type ColorDialog unavailable
file:///C:/Qt/5.12.6/mingw73_32/qml/QtQuick/Dialogs/DefaultDialogWrapper.qml:41 plugin cannot be loaded for module "QtQuick.Controls": Cannot load library C:\Qt\5.12.6\mingw73_32\qml\QtQuick\Controls\qtquickcontrolsplugind.dll: Not enough storage is available to process this command.
```

So I decided to Compromise with ColorPicker and I tried to use a Simple Dialogue with EditBox but the same Error it gave to me.
I tried using the same ColorDialogue in my QML Practice Project and it worked fine there.
I can't understand how this problem can fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debug library `C:\Qt\5.12.6\mingw73_32\qml\QtQuick\Controls\qtquickcontrolsplugind.dll` is too big to be loaded in one piece into memory it seems. The same as described here https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-64551 . Two questions for you:

1. Why do you use 32-bit MinGW while 64-bit is available? Is there any specific requirement for this? Do you want it to run on older systems?
2. Does `Release` build work? From your question, it's clear that you're running debug configuration.

Are you sure that there is enough memory available when you debug your application? Otherwise, it seems like a bug.

Comment: changing to Release Version worked for me. Thank you for instant help.